# Let’sEncrypt の証明書の削除の仕方

Tags: ssl

Let’s encrypt で、証明書を発行済状態で、その証明書をスクリプトから削除したいのです。
以下のような形で破棄、削除を試みてるんですが、

1.証明書破棄
sudo certbot-auto revoke --cert-path={cert.pem.path} -n

2.証明書削除
sudo certbot-auto delete -d {domain} -n

２の時に、削除するドメインを選択してくださいみたいな形で応答待ちになってしまいます。
オプション-nを付けても、選びなさいということで、削除が実行されません。

-d　で指定されているものと思っていたのですが、-dで指定したドメイン以外も候補にあがってきて、選択を促されます。

インタラクティブではなく、スクリプトから既存の証明書を削除したいのですが、どなたか解決策をご存じの方いらっしゃらないでしょうか？
よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ユーザーガイドに以下のサンプルが載っていました。

```
certbot delete --cert-name example.com
```

https://certbot.eff.org/docs/using.html#changing-a-certificate-s-domains

Comment: オプションを-d ではなく、--cert-name を使うと、考えている動作になりました！ありがとうございます。